# How to get a UserPrincipal object for the manager from the employee's UserPrincipal object

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have an Active Directory searcher to get users' details using `UserPrincipal` objects. I'm using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and it's accessing AD through a context.

However, I also need to get the user's manager as a separate `UserPrincipal` object. What would be the most direct way to go about this?

I have tried the following but unfortunately the cast won't work:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
UserPrincipal manager = (UserPrincipal)directoryEntry.Properties["manager"][0];
```

I hoped there would be a `UserPrincipal` property called `UsersManager` inside every UserPrincipal object but I'm unable to find this so I'm guessing there's no such thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manager attribute will give you the distinguished name of the manager's account, which is just a string. So you'll have to look up the manager's account using that DN.

This might work (assuming you already have a `context` object):

```
UserPrincipal manager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, directoryEntry.Properties["manager"][0].ToString());
```

Comment: That one didn't work but this one did:


UserPrincipal manager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, directoryEntry.Properties["manager"][0].ToString());


              so I'm accepting your answer and thanks :)

Comment: Untested code :) I'm glad it helped. I'll update my answer.